# Throwing custom error doesn't preserve Error formatting in the log

Tags: javascript

JavaScript, when `throw`-ing a built-in error as such:

```
throw new Error("Something was wrong");
```

displays the text nicely - you can't tell you threw an object
[image]

However, when creating a custom error by *subclassing* the `Error` object (or other error object for that matter), the thrown error is not displayed the same way in the console.

So, by using this code:

```
var ImproperlyConfigured = function(message){
    this.name ="ImproperlyConfigured";
    this.message = message || "The object you tried to construct was improperly configured due to an unknown error";
}
ImproperlyConfigured.prototype = new Error();
```

The following is the output
[image]

I don't like the fact that the object properties (`name` and `message`) are shown. In fact, I don't like that I don't understand **why** the properties are shown.

I've googled a bit and I got the feeling that by implementing a `toString` method will help but, by using this method, the fact that the name of the error is no longer in red puzzles me even more.

Code

```
var ImproperlyConfigured = function(message){
    this.name ="ImproperlyConfigured";
    this.message = message || "The object you tried to construct was improperly configured due to an unknown error";
    this.toString = function(){
        return this.message;
    }
}
ImproperlyConfigured.prototype = new Error();
```

Output:
[image]

What I would like to achieve is a standard looking error, by the use of custom error and, of course, by not using the `console.error` method manually in a `try...catch` block.

Is this possible?

Comment: I just tried your code in Chromium and [the output was fine](http://i.imgur.com/TPVpkHB.png). In what software/console were you testing ?

Comment: Developer consoles don't follow any particular standard, and they pretty much do what they want.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'm currently using [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) Version 49.0.2623.110 m

Comment: @Pointy - Can you post that as an answer? I wrongly assumed we can control how an error looks in the console from JavaScript, but this issue has nothing to do with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pointy correctly pointed out *(pun intended)*, the issue here is not with JavaScript, but rather with the environment JavaScript is running (in this case, Google Chrome).

In another environment (like Chromium, Firefox, NodeJS, etc.)  the behavior will likely be different, using the same code, depending on how those JavaScript hosts are handling these cases.