# Array adds additional square brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My issue is with SCORES, when I console.log the entire object the scores part is somehow showing an extra set of brackets.

```
$(".submit").on("click", function() {

  var newRoommate = {
    "firstname": $('#first_name').val().trim(),
    "lastname": $('#last_name').val().trim(),
    "photo": $('#user_photo').val().trim(),
    scores: [
      $('#question_1').val(),
      $('#question_2').val(),
      $('#question_3').val(),
      $('#question_4').val(),
      $('#question_5').val(),
      $('#question_6').val(),
      $('#question_7').val(),
      $('#question_8').val(),
      $('#question_9').val(),
      $('#question_10').val()
    ],
    scoresInput
  };
  console.log(newRoommate); // .... scores[]: Array(10)
```

Why is it showing scores[]:?

Ideally, I want it to result in something like this when console.log.

```
{
    firstname:"Ricky",
    lastname:"Bobby",
    photo:"http://www.topcelebsjackets.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Talladega-Nights-Wonder-Bread-Ricky-Bobby-Jacket-6-570x708.jpg",
    scores:[
        5,
        1,
        4,
        4,
        5,
        1,
        2,
        5,
        4,
        1
      ]
  }
```

Comment: That is just a visualization of arrays when you log them. It does not really *add* anything to the array itself.

Comment: You are looking for `console.log(JSON.stringify( newRoommate ) )` maybe?

Comment: Apparantly that is what your browser produces when it logs an array object. Could be the result of the browser first doing scores.toString(), but hard to tell from a distance.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome, Firefox, NodeJS, etc. will have different result for the same `console.log` statement.

That is because `console.log` is not a function delivered by JS, but actually an implementation delivered differently with each environment that JS is running on. If you'd take the raw JS (for example, [Chrome V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/)) you'd notice that `console` is not even defined (among others like `document` or `window`)

In your case, `scores[]: Array(10)` is actually saying that *you have a `scores` key, which is an array, and has 10 elements*.

Related:
[Throwing custom error doesn't preserve Error formatting in the log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664747/throwing-custom-error-doesnt-preserve-error-formatting-in-the-log)

Comment: Thanks, Adelin! I was suspicious that this was being produced by the browser and this helped clarify.